# parsing XML file in python2.7

Tags: python

I know this is a very common question, but the kind of XML file and the kind of extraction of data i need is a little unique due to the nature of the xml file. So appreciate any help on the steps to extract the required data, with `pyhton2.7`

I have the below XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Mango.XYZ_DIG_Team_ABCDEF_Mango_Review</members>
        <members>Mango.XYZ_DIG_Team_Reporting_Mango_Review</members>
        <members>Opportunity.A_T_Occupier_City_Job_List</members>
        <name>ListView</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Modify_All_Data_Permission</members>
        <members>Opportunity_Alerts_Implementation</members>
        <members>Process_Builder_Permission</members>
        <members>Regional_Business_Support</members>
        <members>Reports_Dashboards_Data_Export_for_Super_Users</members>
        <name>PermissionSet</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>SolutionManager</members>
        <members>Standard</members>
        <name>Profile</name>
    </types>
     <types>
        <members>Mango.Set Verified Date and System Id</members>
        <members>Mango.Update Mango Site With Billing Street%2C City%2C Country</members>
        <members>Mango.Update Family Id on Mango when created</members>
        <members>Opportunity.Set Opportunity Name</members>
        <name>WorkflowRule</name>
    </types>
    <version>38.0</version>
</Package>
```

i am trying to extract only the `members` from the `PermissionSet` block. So that eventually i will have a file, that only have the entries like

```
    Modify_All_Data_Permission
    Opportunity_Alerts_Implementation
    Process_Builder_Permission
    Regional_Business_Support
    Reports_Dashboards_Data_Export_for_Super_Users
```

I have been able to extract only the 'name' tag by

```
from xml.dom import minidom

doc = minidom.parse("path_to_xmlFile")


t = doc.getElementsByTagName("types")
for n in t:
    name = n.getElementsByTagName("name")[0]
    print name.firstChild.data
```

How can i extract the members and save that to a file?

Note: the number of 'members' are not fixed they varies. 
I can also try with a different library, if it serves the  purpose.

Comment: Use `"members"` rather than `"name"`?

Comment: Curious. Have you seen this documentation? Your XML is unique, but you can apply any parsing logic to all XML files. https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: believe me, i have looked into that as well

Comment: So if you remove `[0]` and have `n.getElementsByTagName("members")`, what does that give you? Just print `name` variable

Comment: if you remove [0], it doesnt have the idea for the `child` of which its trying to get the `data`

Comment: Right, but you have a list of objects. Just `print name`

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest to use XPath

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse('file.xml').getroot()
for member in root.findall(".//members/")
    print(member.text)
```

Comment: unfortunately, this does nothing, and moreover you are trying to print all the `members`. But i need only the ones for the `name` PermissionSet

Comment: Does nothing? I ran this over your exact text... I don't know if you can get "the PermissionSet block"  very easily without adding that as an attribute to the outer type tag

Answer (score 0):

This may help you!

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for data in root[1]:
   print data.text
```

Comment: thanks, but the xml varies so the index [1] is not always the constant index. i think, as @cricket_007 suggested i need to use Xpath